# operating system that will run on a flash drive?

Tags: usb, operating-systems, usb-flash-drive, emulation

Do you know of anything like [mojopac](http://mojopac.com/) that will emulate your operating system?
Ive already tried mojopac but no luck because the free version of the software does not allow it to run without running a real operating system as an administrator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MojoPac does not include the operating system on the flash drive and requires that the host PC be Windows XP based. It seems to be a way of turning (possibly) any installed app into a [portable app](http://portableapps.com/). Your alternatives are to use the aforementioned portable apps or any of the very many linux/bsd/dos distributions that use syslinux to install on a USB stick. For example [Damn Small Linux](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/usb.html).
A full OS on USB requires either rebooting or virtualization however.

Answer (score 7):

You can get pretty much any distribution of Linux to run on a Flash drive.  Lifehacker [did a handy walkthrough](http://lifehacker.com/391067/fedora-9-puts-your-desktop-on-a-usb-drive) on doing just that with Fedora.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Pendrive Linux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/) for loads of great tutorials on running Linux distros from a USB flash drive.